# Unable to accept User Input to write to a file using PrintWriter

Tags: java, text-files, printwriter

I have been working on an assignment for an online course I've been taking a local CC and it has been driving me up a wall. I thought that my code theoretically was sound, but every time I try to run the program, things aren't going as I would have anticipated. Essentially, the program is supposed to prompt the user to input a line of text and write to to a file of his/her naming. When I execute this code (and this is only a snippet since the program is supposed to have options to read/write in a text and binary file).

When compiled and after I indicate my choices on some of the options, I never get the opportunity to "Enter a line of information to write to the file:". That section always get skipped and the program just jumps right to the "Would you like to enter another line?" section.

I know for a fact that the file is being created, but what am I doing wrong here. Why am I not able to accept user input?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class AshbaughAssignmentFiveTest {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the file name: ");
    String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Choose binary or text file (b/t): ");
    char fileType = keyboard.next().trim().charAt(0);
    System.out.print("Choose read or write (r/w): ");
    char actionType = keyboard.next().trim().charAt(0);

    if ((fileType == 'T' || fileType == 't') && (actionType == 'W' || actionType == 'w'))
    {
        String line = null;
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;

        try
        {
            outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName + ".txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file \"" + fileName + "\".");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("Enter a line of information to write to the file: ");
        line = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputStream.println(line);

        System.out.println("Would you like to enter another line? (Y/N only)");
        char proceed = keyboard.next().trim().charAt(0);

        while (proceed == 'Y' || proceed == 'y')
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a line of information to write to the file: ");
            line = keyboard.nextLine();
            outputStream.println(line);
            System.out.println("Would you like to enter another line? (Y/N only)");
            proceed = keyboard.next().trim().charAt(0);
        }
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So thr problem is in the `keyboard.nextLine()`? Have you confirmed it by step-by-step debugging or breakpoints?

Comment: It may be an issue with keyboard.nextLine() though I also thought that might be that I am using FileOutputStream incorrectly. I'll have to give your method a try and see if it works.

Comment: use `return` instead of `System.exit(0);`

Comment: I think there may be a null pointer issue when I am initializing outputStream. Although the code compiles just fine, the compiler warns me of a potential "null pointer" issue that could occur when I invoke `outputstream.print(line);`. Anyone have any thoughts about that?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `readLine` method proposed [here](http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/java/readLine/).

```
String lineText = "";

System.out.println("Enter a line of text: ");
InputStreamReader converter = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(converter);

lineText = in.readLine();
System.out.println("You typed: " + lineText);
```

Hope I helped!